# Adult entertainment, avoiding the awkwardness

Tags: germany, nightlife

I am travelling with a group of male pals to Germany, and so far as I have researched, in german FKK clubs or saunas, the male guests are not supposed to wear street clothes, which feels awkward for me. I'd feel uncomfortable in such situation.

Are there big clubs in Germany were male guests can keep their clothes on and talk to the girls, have a drink in a relaxed setting?

That's, I don't want no one of my friends to feel pressured, just to be able to hang out at a bar, talk to girls,watch them, have plenty of choice, and so on.

Comment: Any bar in the red light area of German cities is like that. That's why they are in that one street. If you find the one which isn't, it's where the pimps have a drink.

Comment: I think you got the complete wrong end of the stick what an FKK club or a sauna is. The whole point is that you wear no clothes, just like the other visitors (male and female, from 6 to 90). If you feel uncomfortable without clothes, you need to loosen up. And behave yourself if you don't want to get thrown out. It has nothing to do with sex.

Comment: @gnasher729: I think OP is referring to a [*Kontaktsauna*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontaktsauna) (aka. *Saunaclub*, aka. [*FKK-Club*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKK-Club)), not a normal sauna nor a normal FKK place. In a *Kontaktsauna*, people younger than 18 aren’t allowed.

Comment: @unor Op will have lots of fun in _any_ sauna keeping their clothes on :-)

Answer (score 13):

Your question is so full of euphemisms (adult entertainment, club, sauna) that I am not 100% sure what you are asking about, but I'll give it a try.

If you are looking for a whore house, where you as a male customer can enter in regular clothes and have a chat, pick a girl and take her to a private room for paid sexual services: Yes, there are plenty of them in Germany. The common German term is *Puff*.

*FKK* (free body culture) is the German term for nudism and without necessarily defining themselfes as nudists, Germans usually go nude in a sauna. Neither nudist clubs, nor regular saunas are necessarily the right place to look for sex, at least not paid services.

What you might have read about are swinger clubs (which also go under different names and may or may not have a bathing or sauna area). Those are clubs, where people go to seek casual sex with other guests and not for payment. Clothing may or may not be optional.

Comment: A little internet searching reveals that there are also sauna clubs, sometimes confusingly called FKK clubs, that exist primarily as a place for selling sexual services for sale.  I hesitate to include a link because I do not want to endorse a particular site, and because the sites I did visit are very much "not suitable for work" (nor for most other social contexts).

Comment: @phoog You are probably right. I am not *that* familiar with the subject.

Comment: Hm.  Editing error in the previous comment ("selling ... for sale").  Anyway, it's certainly difficult to become familiar with "risqué" things with all the euphemisms floating around.  Thanks for calling attention to that.

Comment: @phoog I can only find very little usage of *FKK-Club* in the context of 'proper' nudism, e.g. for a holiday resorts, but that is how I would have interpreted it if I had read it somewhere. It seems however that nudists are avoiding the term, as it is almost solely used for sex clubs.